# Can the OP request moderator to migrate his asked question to a different site and when an OP does so, is more importance given to the request?

Tags: discussion, migration

As all of us here know SO itself incorporates all kind of programming questions. But later different sites have emerged with aims on different particular branches related to programming and to a certain depth. Now my question is can the OP ask the moderators after asking his question in a not-so-fit-site to migrate his own question to a different better-fit site for a better answer or for whatever the reason might be? I know the process of migration and voting etc. but when the OP himself intends to, should not it be done in no time? Like, after an OP asks a unix question in SO, he can think to migrate it to unix.SO and his request should not be **turned down** as he himself asked the question!

Example- I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789796/please-help-me-understand-lr-rotaoin-in-avl-tree%5C) in SO and just today I discovered there is a computer science SO and according to me, the question should be migrated there. Now my request is not invalid IMHO. So I think when **I** myself request for it, it should be done.

Comment: Were you actually turned down, or is it just taking a while? There can be a lot of flags to go through… or are you asking for it to be automatic?

Comment: @minitech, No I did not request till now, but I fear I might be turned down saying the fact there are lots of questions with the same issue and if every OP request so there would be a lot of questions to be migrated to.

Answer (score 14):

There are several cases.

#### The question is firmly on-topic

We don't normally migrate questions that are firmly on-topic, even if there is another site where they would be on-topic.

#### The question is firmly off-topic

It will be closed whether the asker wants that or not. The question may be migrated if there is another site where it is on-topic. Moderators (or community voters where applicable) decide whether they think the question would be suitable for the proposed target site. They may ask regulars of the target site for advice.

#### The question is borderline

This is the only case where the asker's opinion matters. Assuming that the question is suitable both where it is and on the proposed target site, we tend to look at the following criteria:

- Is the question more mainstream for the proposed target site than where it is now?
- Does the question already have good answers? (If not, this is a hint that it has reached the wrong audience.)
- Does the asker wish for the migration?

#### [This particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789796/please-help-me-understand-lr-rotaoin-in-avl-tree)

- This is a pure data structures question with no actual programming involved. There is no consensus on whether such questions are on-topic or off-topic on Stack Overflow. It would be a perfect fit for Computer Science. Strike one for migration.
- There is a correct answer. This question doesn't need any extra attention. Furthermore, the answer is “there is an error in the book”, which makes it a very localized question that won't help many people. Strike two against migration.
- You want the migration. Strike one for migration.

Speaking as a moderator on CS.SE, sure, we'd take it, but it's a pretty boring question given that the answer turned out to be an error in the book, so we may as well let it rest. I do however encourage you to ask future questions about computer science on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The thing is I am learning DataStructure you know, so did not show the boldness to say that the picture in the book is wrong outright even after the answer was posted. The question did not attract too much traffic and before I posted the meta here, there was not a single vote on that answer. So you know I was not sure about the answer the whole time.

Answer (score 8):

You can flag a question for moderator attention, using the "other" flag reason and explaining the reasoning for asking for migration (you may want to include why you hasn't asked on the migration target in the first place, though this isn't a requirement).

When moderators get involved in migration, they will often ask the moderators of the migration target if they "want" that question - that is, if it is of high enough quality and is on-topic for them.

Some questions would obviously be unsuitable for migration (low quality, vague, open-ended etc...).

In general, moderators will not look at who raised the flag - so being the OP is not relevant to the decision.

> should not it be done in no time?

Why? Where's the fire? Why should it be done immediately? If it is on-topic where asked, no harm done.

Moderators are busy with many duties and on a busy site like Stack Overflow it can take quite a while to get to the latest flag.